# How to merge two dataframes so I can get one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 data frames:
First:

```
result:
     mcc_code  category
163      7996         6
142      7372         5
160      7993         4
161      7994         4
146      7512         3
160      7993         7
161      7994         7
172      8220         2
174      8299         2
39       5137         1
69       5611         1
70       5621         1
72       5641         1
73       5651         1
74       5655         1
77       5691         1
78       5697         1
79       5699         1
```

Second:

```
df
        customer_id   tr_datetime  mcc_code  ...    amount   term_id gender
828        39026145  372 08:45:27      5621  ... -31442.82    097179    1.0
829        39026145  372 08:48:29      5621  ... -11229.58    097179    1.0
1109       52220754   38 16:48:36      5691  ... -68433.05       NaN    1.0
1444       52220754  178 19:11:10      5691  ... -17742.73       NaN    1.0
1540       52220754  240 10:44:52      5691  ... -49163.10    579031    1.0
...             ...           ...       ...  ...       ...       ...    ...
998285      8942066  436 00:00:00      5691  ...  -1437.39     SN271    1.0
999808     98801178   26 09:46:26      5641  ... -30095.27       NaN    0.0
999840     98801178  100 00:00:00      5621  ... -41549.44       NaN    0.0
999891     98801178  157 00:00:00      5641  ... -27624.76       NaN    0.0
999980     98801178  253 00:00:00      5691  ... -15272.23  77076560    0.0
```

How do I add to df category of mcc code from result? I've tried joins, but they resulted in increasing the number of rows.

Comment: You can have a look at this, https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: *but they resulted in increasing the number of rows* which means you have non-unique `mcc_code`, e.g. `7993`. Which category you choose to map, `5` or `7`? `merge`, by default, will duplicate your data so as you have both `5` and `7` in the new data.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have multiple values for the same mcc_code in the first dataframe. You will have to first check how many values are duplicated by doing:

```
result[result['mcc_code'].duplicated()]
```

Then you will need to figure out why 1 mcc_code can have multiple categories, which is a data quality issue.